# Can't Connect to my Simple Http Server on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ or external IP

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, localhost, simplehttpserver

I have python 3.8.1 installed on my Windows 10 PC.

I run the following command from PowerShell in the directory I want to set as server

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

I get the following response after running the command

> Serving HTTP on :: port 8000 (http://[::]:8000/) ...

I'm **able to access** the directory **on localhost:8000** but *not 0.0.0.0:8000 or http://127.0.0.1:8000/*

I can't access the server on my external Ip from the same PC or a different PC on the Same network.

I checked the firewall to make sure Python was an accepted app and  my network was set to private.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the documentation didn't state this. I presumed that the server wasn't binding to all the available ports. 
In PowerShell, I tried running

```
python -m http.server 8000 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

I got the following response instead

> Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...

I was able to access the Server on the following addresses

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/
- http://localhost:8000/
- externalip:8000 (on both the same PC and a PC connected on the same network)

Hope this helps someone other than me